# Why positive text file doesn't create the samples

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to do face detection, for which I am creating my own XML file. I have two folders - one for storing positive images, and another for storing negative images. I am creating the description file of both, named positive.txt and negative.txt. The file positive.txt contains a total of 2676 images and negative.txt contains a total of 581 images. Now I want to create the vec file of positive.txt, using the following command:

`opencv_createsamples -info positive.txt -vec vefile.vec -num 2676 -w 24 -h 24`.

However, I am getting an error. Here is the output:

```
Info file name: positive.txt
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: vefile.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 2676
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 24
Height: 24
Create training samples from images collection...

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 && rect.x <        image->width && rect.y < image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.width > 0) && rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0)) in cvSetImageROI, file /home/arya/stuff/opencv/opencv-2.4.7/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 3006
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/arya/stuff/opencv/opencv-2.4.7/modules/core/src/array.cpp:3006: error: (-215) rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 && rect.x < image->width && rect.y < image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.width > 0) && rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0) in function cvSetImageROI

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here are a few examples of the information which positive.txt contains about the 2676 images:

```
/home/arya/myown/Positive/Pictures1102.jpeg 2 414 271 40 51 547 289 37 52
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images460.jpeg 1 108 21 93 127
/home/arya/myown/Positive/Pictures1131.jpeg 3 298 418 62 81 443 316 42 52 656 346 50 52
/home/arya/myown/Positive/face294.jpeg 1 189 84 45 57
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images129.jpeg 1 115 22 84 112
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images724.jpeg 1 128 19 89 106
/home/arya/myown/Positive/Pictures489.jpeg 1 237 418 49 75
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images90.jpeg 1 106 19 93 116
/home/arya/myown/Positive/Pictures1246.jpeg 1 964 117 131 153
/home/arya/myown/Positive/face922.jpeg 2 218 175 74 74 274 155 0 0
```

What could be causing the above error?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs, when it is setting ROI of image. Create samples utility takes the object location from your txt file and setting the ROI by given location rectangular.  For example :

```
(414 271 40 51)
```

is a bounding rectangle, first two integer is the position and last two is the width and height of the rectangle. If this rectangle does not fit supplied image it will give this assertion error. So what might be wrong :

**1.** Supplied rectangles may be not given in the respected order.

**2.** Supplied rectangles may not belong the given picture.